# How to increase the maximum scale of the Photoshop filter (glass filter)

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photoshop-effects, filter, scale

I applied Glass Filter (from PS "Filter Gallery") to a layer. But because I am working on a 4000x4000px document, I need a bigger scale than 200% which is the maximum I can set. How to achieve that?

I tried the following workaround: Turn a layer into a smart object > apply Glass filter (smart filter) > turn all of that into a new smart object > scale up.

The filter is bigger now, but lower quality.

I can use a texture, but there are two problems then: Usually the textures are not evenly lit, and second, no matter the texture image size, it's rare that the "actual effect size" (the dot or grain of the effect) is big enough.

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: While I've never needed an image that large, I'd create a seamless tile... then tile to the size I need.

Comment: Hi @Scott, thanks for your answer! The thing is that I don't need a large area to cover. What I need is a small area with a scale (let's say) of 400%, so the effect is clearly pronounced even when the large photo is zoomed out.  

In other words, you can have a large area covered with a tiny texture scale. I need a small area, but with large texture scale :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think there's in way to increase the scale of the applied effect beyond 200%. You're left with scaling layers after the effect is applied.

Comment: I understand, thanks.